# SpriteKit crashes on iOS10 / Sierra

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit

My Spritekit App is fine on iOS8, iOS9 but when I start it in iOS10 I get the following assertion error on every start:

```html
validateFunctionArguments:2658: failed assertion `missing buffer binding at index 2 for u_light_position[0].'
```

If I set PrefersOpenGL = YES, to turn off Metal I just get:

```
#0  0x0000000119dcdc12 in jet_context_OpenGL::set_vertex_constant(jet_constant*, int) ()
```

The app doesn't have any OpenGL code, all graphics are written in SpriteKit so this looks like a bug in the OpenGL calls internal to SpriteKit.

It all works fine on iOS8 and iOS9 but on 10 it consistently crashes with this error at every start.. has anyone ever seen something like this?

EDIT: I did find some mentions of SKEmitterNodes behaving weirdly on iOS10, but I'm not using those either.

Comment: Put an exception break point and see if execution will stop at certain point.

Comment: @Whirlwind yup, thats what I did, the stacktrace for the jet_context_OpenGL issue is just 'UIApplicationMain', no information at all :(
(Makes sense right? As OpenGL crashes would not happen right after the SpriteKit call that might be ultimately responsible as the OpenGL execution inside the apple frameworks happens at a later time)